# Spark read.json with file names

Tags: json, apache-spark

I need to read a bunch of JSON files from an HDFS directory. After I'm done processing, Spark needs to place the files in a different directory. In the meantime, there may be more files added, so I need a list of files that were read (and processed) by Spark, as I do not want to remove the ones that were *not* yet processed.

The function `read.json` converts the files immediately into DataFrames, which is cool but it does not give me the file names like `wholeTextFiles`. Is there a way to read JSON data while also getting the file names? Is there a conversion from RDD (with JSON data) to DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

From version1.6 on you can use `input_file_name()` to get the name of the file in which a row is located. Thus, getting the names of all the files can be done via a distinct on it.

Comment: I forgot to add: I'm on 1.4.1.

Comment: No way around it in pre-1.6.0?

Comment: Actually I don't know, this function is broken earlier than 1.6. the only thing I can think about is to parse your JSON data with a JSON parser, but this is exactly what you're trying to avoid..

Comment: Another option would be to copy the files temporarily to another folder, work on that, and when done move them either back (in case of failure) or to the final location (in case of success).